# Restricting a Char to Two Values in Oracle

Tags: database, oracle, plsql

I'm creating a table in PL/SQL, but I want my `char` column to only be allowed to be `r` or `d`. I've been looking around but haven't found a concrete answer to it online. Maybe I'm just not using the right search term.

Comment: If the column can't be NULL either you should add a NOT NULL constraint.  Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE tablename
ADD CONSTRAINT constraintname
  CHECK (columnname IN ('r', 'd'));
```

[Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/clauses002.htm#sthref2913)